# Show that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|S_n'|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}} < \infty$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose that $\{X_n\}_n$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables. Put $S_n:= \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ and assume that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n\log \log n}}< \infty\quad a.s.$$

Put $X_j':= X_{2j}-X_{2j-1}, j \geq1$ and $S_n' := \sum_{j=1}^n X_j'$. Can we deduce that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|S_n'|}{\sqrt{n\log \log n}}< \infty\quad a.s.$$

**Attempt**: This is used in the proof of the converse of the law of the iterated logarithm, so I can't definitely use that the second moments exist as this is the end goal.

I tried to arrange $|S_n'| = |\sum_{j=1}^n X_{2j}- \sum_{j=1}^n X_{2j-1}|$ so I can tell estimate it with |S_n| or something like that but I'm clearly overseeing something.

Comment: When they use the result in the converse part of LIL they are replacing ${X_i}$ by ${X_i'}$. Do you have a specific reason to think that this is not the case? Can you give a reference to the book you are reading?

Comment: I don't, these are just lecture notes. The statement I'm proving is: Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. Then $\limsup_n |S_n|/\sqrt{n \log \log n} < \infty \quad a.s.$ implies $\mathbb{E}X_1^2 < \infty, \mathbb{E}X_1 = 0$. Maybe it should rather say: if $\limsup_n |S_n|/\sqrt{n \log \log n} < \infty$ a.e. for all i.i.d sequences $\{X_n\}_n$, then $\mathbb{E}X_1^2 < \infty, \mathbb{E}X_1 = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_i=X_{2i}$ and $V_i=X_{2i-1}$. Then $(U_i)$ is equivalent to $(X_i)$ in the sense the two sequeces have the same finite dimensional distributions. Similarly, $(V_i)$ is equivalent to $(X_i)$. Hence $\lim \sup \frac {|T_n|}{\sqrt {n\log \log n}} <\infty$ a.s.  and $\lim \sup \frac {|Z_n|}{\sqrt {n\log \log n}}<\infty$ a.s where $T_n$ an d $Z_n$ are the partial sums of $(U_n)$ and $(V_n)$. This implies your result.

Comment: I know that if $\mathbb{P}_{(X_1, \dots, X_n)} = \mathbb{P}_{(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)}$ for all $n \geq 1$, then $\limsup_n X_n$ has the same distribution as $\limsup_n Y_n$. How did you prove that $\mathbb{P}_{(X_1, \dots, X_n)} = \mathbb{P}_{(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)}$  in this particular example?

Comment: @user661541 Since $X_i$'s are i.i.d. these joint distributions are nothing but $P_{X_1}\times P_{X_1}\times ...\times P_{X_1}$ (product of $n$ copies of $P_{X_1}$).

Comment: Yes, I know but if we put $A_n:= |T_n|/\sqrt{n \log\log n}$ and similarly $B_n:=|Z_n|/\sqrt{n \log\log n}$, we have to show $(A_1, \dots, A_n)$ is equal in distribution to $(B_1,\dots , B_n)$ and now they aren't iid anymore.

Comment: @user661541 Are familiar with  the measure induced by an infinite sequence of random variables on $\mathbb R^{\infty}$? The sequences  $(X_i)$, $(U_i)$ and $(V_i)$ al in deice then same measure on $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ and $\{(a_n): \lim  \sup \frac {|s_n|} {\sqrt {nloglog n}} <\infty$ is  Borel set in $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ (where $s_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$)

Comment: I think I don't know that.